# How to add a smooth animation to the progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click I want to smoothly add segments to the progress bar. They are added but instantly. What could be the problem?

[image: demonstration of problem]

I tried to implement a smooth animation with `setInterval`, but nothing comes out. Percentages are also added instantly.

```js
let progressBar = document.querySelector(".progressbar");
let progressBarValue = document.querySelector(".progressbar__value");
const body = document.querySelector("body");

let progressBarStartValue = 0;
let progressBarEndValue = 100;
let speed = 50;

body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (progressBarStartValue === progressBarEndValue) {
    alert("you have completed all the tasks");
  } else {
    let progress = setInterval(() => {
      if (progressBarStartValue != 100) {
        progressBarStartValue += 10;
        clearInterval(progress);
      }
      progressBarValue.textContent = `${progressBarStartValue}%`;
      progressBar.style.background = `conic-gradient(
                #FFF ${progressBarStartValue * 3.6}deg,
                #262623 ${progressBarStartValue * 3.6}deg
            )`;
    }, speed);
  }
});
```

```css
.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #262623;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.progressbar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.progressbar__value {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <section class="statistic">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="statistic__inner">
        <div class="statistic__text">
          <h2 class="statistic__title">You're almost there!</h2>
          <p class="statistic__subtitle">keep up the good work</p>
        </div>
        <div class="progressbar"><span class="progressbar__value">0%</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but with the `conic-gradient()` implementation you're using, I'd recommend checking out a library call `anime.js`.

Here's an example with your implementation (same html and css):

```
// your.js

let progressBar = document.querySelector(".progressbar");
let progressBarValue = document.querySelector(".progressbar__value");
const body = document.querySelector("body");

// Switched to object for target in anime()
let progressBarObject = {
  progressBarStartValue: 0,
  progressBarEndValue: 100,
  progressBarAnimationValue: 0 * 3.6 // New value needed for smoothing the progress bar, since the progress value needs to be multiplied by 3.6
}

// Not necessary, but I recommend changing the event listener to pointerup for better support
// Also not necessary, I changed function to arrow function for my own preference
body.addEventListener("pointerup", e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  if (progressBarObject.progressBarStartValue === progressBarObject.progressBarEndValue) {
    alert("you have completed all the tasks");
  } else {
    let newValue = 0 // Needed so we can set the value, before it's applied in anime()
    if (progressBarObject.progressBarStartValue != 100) {
      // Math.ceil() allows us to round to the nearest 10 to guarantee the correct output
      newValue = Math.ceil((progressBarObject.progressBarStartValue + 10) / 10) * 10;
    }
    // Optional: Prevents accidentally going over 100 somehow
    if (newValue > 100) {
      newValue = 100
    }
    anime({
      targets: progressBarObject,
      progressBarStartValue: newValue,
      progressBarAnimationValue: newValue * 3.6,
      easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
      round: 1, // Rounds to nearest 1 so you don't have 0.3339...% displayed in progressBarValue
      update: () => {
        progressBar.style.backgroundImage = `conic-gradient(
          #FFF ${progressBarObject.progressBarAnimationValue}deg,
          #262623 ${progressBarObject.progressBarAnimationValue}deg)`;
        progressBarValue.textContent = `${progressBarObject.progressBarStartValue}%`;
      },
      duration: 500
    });
  }
});
```

Here's a CodePen using the `anime.js` CDN: [Circular Progress Bar Smoothing](https://codepen.io/andrilla/pen/jOKEWRz?editors=0011)

If you don't want to use a javascript library, then I'd recommend switching from the `conic-gradient()` to something else. I hear using an `.svg` circle with `stroke` and `stroke-dasharray` can work great with CSS `transition`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't `setInterval` your `progress` variable like this. instead, put it as a **global variable** outside the `function` then use it to **gradually** add `1` as long as the `start value` is `less than` `progress`, and you still can control the speed with your `speed` variable.

```js
let progressBar = document.querySelector(".progressbar");
  let progressBarValue = document.querySelector(".progressbar__value");
  const body = document.querySelector("body");
  
  let progressBarStartValue = 0;
  let progressBarEndValue = 100;
  let speed = 50;
  let progress = 0;
  
  body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (progressBarStartValue === progressBarEndValue) {
      alert("you have completed all the tasks");
    } else {
      
      progress += 10;
      
       setInterval(() => {
        if (progressBarStartValue < progress) {
          progressBarStartValue += 1;
          clearInterval();
        }

        progressBarValue.textContent = `${progressBarStartValue}%`;
        progressBar.style.background = `conic-gradient(
                  #FFF ${progressBarStartValue * 3.6}deg,
                  #262623 ${progressBarStartValue * 3.6}deg
              )`;
      }, speed);
    }
  });
```

```css
.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #262623;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
  
}

.progressbar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #0f0f0f;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.progressbar__value {
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
    <section class="statistic">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="statistic__inner">
          <div class="statistic__text">
            <h2 class="statistic__title">You're almost there!</h2>
            <p class="statistic__subtitle">keep up the good work</p>
          </div>
          <div class="progressbar"><span class="progressbar__value">0%</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
```